# Component call another lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, navigation, navigatetocomponent

I have created a lightning component onclick button call a js function. Js function is there.

```
callAuthComponent : function(component, event, helper){

  console.log('call......');

    var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent"); 
    evt.setParams({
        componentDef:"c:getAuthComponent",
    });
    evt.fire();
 }
```

But get the following error:

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
>   Action failed: c:LinkedinSalesforce$controller$callAuthComponent [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined]
>   Failing descriptor: {c:LinkedinSalesforce$controller$callAuthComponent}

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: You've tagged your question `salesforce1-app`. Are you experiencing this issue in a component used in Salesforce mobile? If no, can you [edit] your question to specify where you are surfacing this component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `lightning:navigation`. As per the documentation examples [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation), you can setup your PageReference like this (note this PageReference is for navigating to the Account home tab):

```
var navService = cmp.find("navService");

// Sets the route to /lightning/o/Account/home
var pageReference = {
    type: 'standard__objectPage',
    attributes: {
        objectApiName: 'Account',
        actionName: 'home'
    }
};
cmp.set("v.pageReference", pageReference);
```

Once you've setup your PageReference specifically for you lightning component, using `standard__component` as the type to point to your custom component (see [PageReference - Lightning Component Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm), you can use the following to navigate to it:

```
// Get your navService library component
let navService = cmp.find("navService");

// Use navService to setup the right PageReference object
const pageReference = cmp.get("v.pageReference");

// Actually navigate to your component
navService.navigate(pageReference);
```